# EXT js model.load returning undefined record

Tags: extjs, extjs4.1

I am doing a Model.load similar to this:

```
//get a reference to the User model class
var User = Ext.ModelManager.getModel('User');

//Uses the configured RestProxy to make a GET request to /users/123
User.load(123, {
    success: function(user) {
        console.log(user.getId()); //logs 123
    }

});
```

In the console I can see that the correct `User` object is being loaded. The correct server side web service is being called. It is going into the success function. However the `user` is undefined. Does anyone know why this would happen?

Comment: Well, ts hard to say without looking at your JSON response but i think the problem may be with the format of that JSON (maybe its not the root object, maybe its an array?)

Comment: @VoidMain the web service is returning a User object, the console shows a jsonarray {"id":22,"firstname":"ttes","lastname":"fff","phonenumber":"444-444-4444","email":"fff@gmial.com","bio":"asdfsdfasdfdfs","travelradius":6,"accepted":true,"approver":null,"approvercomments":null}

Comment: You say is showing a jsonarray but your json looks like a single object, if it is an array response then you need to unwrap that in your server to get only one result when you load by id (like in your example) the `load` method takes a single result object, not an array, may that be your case? In any case it would be usefull to see you proxy and reader config for that model.

Answer (score 0):

From your description, the console is showing a user object (which is just a bunch of key/value pairs in a JSON response).
You say user is undefined, but it looks like you mean `user.getId()` is undefined.
The JSON response from the web server doesn't have any methods on it (like `getId`) - just key/value pairs.

**EDIT:**  Your code looks a lot like the example given [here](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#/guide/data) (about mid-way down).
If you modify your logging to say this:

```
console.log("User: " + user.get('firstname'));
```

does it return `ttes` like you show in your JSON object?

Comment: no. The user is undefined. I can take off the getId. the actual user is undefined. which is why I'm asking the question

Comment: How does the console show the json array of: {"id": 22, "firstname"...  if its undefined?

Comment: that is why I asked the question

Comment: You're not making any sense.  You say: "the console shows a jsonarray {"id":22, "firstname":...  Is this what it shows for `user`?  If it shows this for user, then obviously `user` isn't undefined.  If you're saying it shows this for something else, then what else?  What is this jsonarray the value of?  How did you log it in the console?

Answer (score 0):

This is a shot in the dark an might not be the correct answer.

I believe you are not returning the correct JSON. First, it will be useful to see the proxy definition on the model, and if you have set any `root` property in its reader.

If you haven't defined any reader root, then try to warp your JSON response with `[` and `]`.

If any of this works I'll explain why.